# how to increase freebase API result limit

Tags: api, freebase

I can't find anything in freebase's docs about it but it seems they limit the number of results to 100. For example:

```
[{
  "type":"/base/popstra/celebrity",
  "name":null
}]
```

Returns only 100 results whereas

```
[{
  "type":"/base/popstra/celebrity",
  return:"count"
}]
```

Says there are 6244 results. Does anyone know how to get the rest of them? I know I can limit the queries by some parameter like country and then aggregate the results but I'd prefer something less hacky.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `limit` property to request more results.  However, fetching large numbers can give you a query timeout.

A more reliable way is to use the `cursor` property.  Pass in a `cursor` value of `true`.  You'll get a batch of results, but you'll also get a new value for `cursor` in the response.  Repeat your query, but substitute in the new `cursor` value to get the next batch of results.  In this way you can fetch even a very large set of data.

More info: http://www.freebase.com/docs/mql/ch04.html#envelopeparameters

Comment: Using their example I received the following message "Key cursor is a reserved word", doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: This still works.  The cursor goes on the envelope, not in the query itself (follow the link Peter provided to the documentation).

Comment: Ah! Thanks Peter, I was wondering how to get the cursor value in the response!

Answer (score 0):

A coworker helped me figure this one out. I thought I should use the `limit` parameter but I didn't put it in the right place. Here's how it's done:

```
[{
  "type":"/base/popstra/celebrity",
  "name":null,
  "limit":300
}]
```

Comment: You should really update your OP or comment on it, instead of providing an answer!