# Large Freebase query with python 2.7 on GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, freebase

I need to query about 30000 entities from Freebase using Python on GAE. This has been my evenings journey so far:

Firstly, I attempted to use the solution using the 'cursor' key from here: [how to increase freebase API result limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318463/how-to-increase-freebase-api-result-limit). But I hit the "Key cursor is a reserved word" error described here: [Freebase "Key cursor is a reserved word"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003317/freebase-key-cursor-is-a-reserved-word). I followed the solution butI could not see how to get the cursor value back as described here: [How to get cursor from mqlread() when using Freebase API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835141/how-to-get-cursor-from-mqlread-when-using-freebase-api). This post recommends using the python freebase library:

```
freebase.mqlread(query, extended=True)
```

So I installed the freebase library on GAE following the instructions here: http://code.google.com/p/freebase-python/wiki/GoogleAppEngine. Next, I got the GAE error:

```
No module named uritemplate
```

So I ran "easy_install uritemplate" on my Mac and copied the installed uritemplate.egg file (no dir was installed) into my GAE app dir. But I still get the same error.

Comment: can you post the directory layout of your App Engine app directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of how to use cursors:
http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/MQL_Read_Service#cursor:_return_albums_by_Bob_Dylan_3_at_a_time

You should not use the freebase-python library as it's not updated to deal with the new googleapis yet.